# Use tcpdump to capture an ICMP destination unreachable message

Tags: linux-networking, tcpdump

I am new in this area. I am asked to use tcpdump to capture an ICMP destination unreachable message in my network course. 
So I am trying to capture one message that is an ICMP destination unreachable and whose destination IP is dst 172.17.1.8. My code is following:

```
sudo tcpdump -c 1 'icmp[0] = 3' and dst 172.17.1.8
```

It shows "tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
"

The problem is, in order to capture the unreachable message, some packets need to be sent to this IP address first. I have tried ping 2 packets to that destination before the code. However, the code won't be executed until the ping is done. So still I can't receive the unreachable message by using tcpdump.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run several commands at once, for example with several command windows. Start tcpdump in one window, then ping in the other window, stop the ping command after a few pings, and then stop tcpdump.

Comment: Thx. I changed ping to tracepath to solve this.